# Notification of one iphone to another iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I working on a personal project where I want to get access notification data of  one iphone another iPhone .I know it is  not possible through public api , so is there any private  api .

My doubts are is this possible

though private api  ?

Or can be make another iPhone a virtual bless device and send notification there ?

Or can we get all notification in our phone and then send to receiving device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apprently we can get all notification from an iPhone to Android device ,it gives all notification to the Android device as it gives to a smartwatch or band . But when connecting it with an iPhone to iPhone we do not get all services

Answer (score 0):

you can get every notification by add UDID with user associated with it

like user have udid associated with it have 2 udid 1 is for user and another one  is your.

Please ask api developer to send notification for associated udid with user

in these method you can get all Notification which are received by user

Comment: Thanks what for the suggestion but ,but I need notification for all apps not a single aap ..like whatsaap sms mail calls etc .. I know we can manage this with MDM but I don't want to use MDM ..I want my make my iPhone like a virtual smart watch ..which recives notification when we revice calls  ,sms and from other aap

Answer (score 0):

Apparently we can receive notification from iPhone to Android device by connecting them to  with Bluetooth . But when connecteing with iPhone to iPhone we do not receive all services